# How to call a view that is located on "Views/Home/Login/Login.cshtml"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to open a view that is located on "Views/Home/Login/Login.cshtml", but when i try to open the page by the website, tell that the page is not found.

I already tried put another kinds of links, like "Login/Login.cshtml".

**My HomeController ActionResult:**

```
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View("Home/Login/Login.cshtml");
        }
```

**Folder:**

```
Views>Home>Login>Login.cshtml
```

**Actual error:**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The view 'Home/Login/Login.cshtml' was not found. The >following locations were searched:
>   /Login/Login.cshtml
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnume>rable originalLocations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your are looking for

```
return View("Login/Login");
```

Another way,
in App_Start RouteConfig.cs a line should read

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

If you are not using template to create your login ability, add the following to your Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

Right click within the above method to create your view in Views Home - No login folder.

You can run your program now, without errors.

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs when your view page was selected as a default `startup page`. So remove it as a `startup page` and pass your default controller and view name in routeConfig.cs file.

`defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

here `action = "Login"` is nothing but a view name.

Comment: thats my startup page code about: ```app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            }); ```   What should i do exactly about? i tried change the id? but it doesnt load the page anyway

Comment: @Vinícius Oliveira Gouveia Select your `Index view` in a solution explorer then right click on it and select `Exclude From Project`, and then again right click on that page.now, select `Include In Project`. I think it may works.